# Regarding function where the slope is infinity or negative infinity

Tags: functions, infinity

**Disclaimer: this is more of a disscussion, rather than a question. if there's a better place to put this, let me know.** 
Say we have an equation $f(x)=mx$ 
 
Where m is the slope. 
 
If $m=\infty$ 
Then $f(x)=\infty x$ 
Which appears to be $x=0$ 
Also, If $f(x)=-\infty$ 
Then $f(x)=-\infty x$ 
Which  **also**  is $x=0$ 
This means that $\infty x=-\infty x$ 
If we divide by x, then we get this: 
$\infty=-\infty$

Now at first, this appears to be wrong. However, go follow  [this link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/efviuzz3he)  to see what i mean. move m close to infinity, and compare this to when m is close to negative infinity. They appear to be the same (if they don't, then set m more closer to infinity/negative infinity).

I want to see your opinions about this. I'm sure that when people see this, they will think i'm wrong, but who knows.

Comment: The equation $$\infty=-\infty$$ is true in contexts that are related to your observation (e.g. both this equation and your derivation of this make sense in the one-point compactification of the real line, or in the Grassmanian $\operatorname{Gr}(1,\mathbb R)$ identifying reals with the line with that slope). However, without a question, it's hard for me to expand this into a proper answer. (And the post isn't really on-topic without a question either)

Comment: i'm not asking for answers, i'm only interested in what people have to say.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, basically, is that infinity is weird.

There are a couple distinct ways to extend the real line to include infinity. One way is to add two elements, one at either "end" of the number line; often they're denoted $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. This gives a structure called the [extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).

Another approach, though, is to view the real line as a sort of horseshoe-shape, where both ends curve around towards each other. In this view, the natural thing to do is to add a *single* point (frustratingly also usually called "$\infty$") which "glues" the ends together. This results in a structure called the [projective real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity), and is also the [one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of the real line.

What you've discovered is that - essentially - **"slope" is a map from $\{$lines$\}$ to the projective real line**, rather than from $\{$lines$\}$ to the extended real line. There are other contexts where the extended real line is the "right" object to be looking at instead of the projective real line.

The crucial methodological takeaway, in my opinion, is:

> The idea of infinity is complicated enough that it has many different instantiations in mathematics; these versions often have wildly different properties, and are more or less useful/interesting/cool depending on the specific context.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about this, i have been thinking of something similar to this for awhile now (and i'm referring to the projectile real line).